# Navigate to completely different screen on React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

On my React Native app I am initially loading SceneA, which simply displays a text "Click me". When this button is clicked I would like to load a completely different screen (SceneB) that has completely different components.

All the examples that I found online (like the example below) load a scene with exactly the same components, but different values. In my case it is a completely different layout. How can I navigate to that new screen (SceneB)?

It is basically the equivalent to a new Activity on Android, passing some data at the same time. Any pointers will be appreciated.

**index.android.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Navigator } from 'react-native';

import SceneA from './SceneA';

class ReactNativeTest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{ title: 'My Initial Scene', index: 0 }}
        renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
          <SceneA
            title={route.title}

            // Function to call when a new scene should be displayed
            loadNewScene={() => {    
              const nextIndex = route.index + 1;
              navigator.push({
                title: 'Scene B',
                index: nextIndex,
              });
            }}
          />
        }
      />
    )
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNativeTest', () => ReactNativeTest);
```

**SceneA.js**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

export default class SceneA extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Scene A</Text>

        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.props.loadNewScene}>
          <Text>Click Me</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

SceneA.propTypes = {
  loadNewScene: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You handle which components should render in the renderScene function, each scene will have a route.title so you can decide which to render based on that.

```
renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
  if (route.title === 'Scene A') {
    return <SceneA navigator={navigator} />
  }
  if (route.title === 'Scene B') {
    return <SceneB navigator={navigator} />
  }
}
```

Then inside your components you're gonna have a function that handles the navigation:

```
navigateToSceneB = () => {
  this.props.navigator.push({
    title: 'Scene B'
  })
}
```